# Django model fields with multiple values

Tags: django, django-models

How can I create a model with a field that is having a list of values? (For example a model called group with multiple members)
Is it possible to implement the relationship with many to many fields?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example with multiple selection options

```
class Members(models.Model):
    MEMBERS = {
        (0, 'James'),
        (1, 'Jeremy'),
        (2, 'Alex'),
    }

    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    names = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=MEMBERS)
```

Comment: Your answer is describing multiple choice where only one value is selected at a time. Whereas the question is asking about choosing multiple values to be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Many2Many Field. For example:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    # relevant fields
    ...

class Team(models.Model):
    # other fields
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teams')
```

Note several things about this solution:

- Users can be members of multiple teams (that is why Many2Many relationship)
- User model can reference all teams, he is part of: `user.teams_set`

If you want a User to be member of only one team, than ForeignKey is the right way to go:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    # other fields
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    ...

class Team(models.Model):
    # relevant fields
    ...
```

For more information consult documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LynxLike. Also how can I add data to the many to many field?

Comment: You simply **add** appropriate model instance to the field. In your example: `team = Team.objects.create(...)` and `user = User.objects.create(...)`. Then you simply assing the user to the team via `team.members.add(user)`

Comment: When I tried printing `team.members` after `team.members.add(user)`  `team.save()` and then it is showing like `User.None`  which means the data is not getting saved to the instance. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I do this one time. if you working with the PostgreSQL database in Django projects, in my search you can do like this

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModal (models.Model):
    array_field= ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True),null=True,blank=True)
```